# Guake terminal displays incorrect colors (insufficient contrast)

Tags: linux, terminal, colors, gtk, kde-plasma

I use two dropdown terminals in parallel: *Yakuake* and *Guake*.

When using *Guake*, the colors are way too dark, which makes much of the colored text unreadable because of insufficient contrast. The problem is most severe when displaying `color #4 (dark blue)` on `black` background (which is the default color `ls` displays directories with) or in *Midnight Commander* (default theme, `dark blue` background).

*Yakuake* displays all 16 colors correctly and the text is readable very well, the colored output of `ls` and *Midnight Commander*.

My OS is *Linux 5.15.11-gentoo* with *plasma-5.88.0*, *gtk+-2.24.33* and *gtk+-3.24.29*. Here is my TERM setting in the environment:

```sh
TERM=xterm-256color
COLORTERM=yes
```

I tried all available *Guake* themes and all of them have horrible contrast. Either all colors are too dark, or the other way around - all of them are too bright. It seems Guake somehow compresses the color contrast.

I also tried defining custom colors, copying the color settings from Yakuake, but even though I set specific colors explicitly, the actually displayed colors were darker. I validated this with a color picker.

Changing the *GTK Theme* setting in Guake's preference tab *General* did not yield any success either.

The question is: **Why does Guake alter the colors? Is there a way to turn this off and let it display the actual colors I specified?** The problem must be with Guake or GTK because everything else is identical when using Yakuake (environment, *Midnight Commander* colors, `ls` colors, ...)

The following screenshots demonstrate my *Guake Appearance* settings:

[image: Guake Preferences, Appearance]

[image: Guake Preferences, General]

And here is some Guake support information:

```
<details><summary>$ guake --support</summary>
Guake Version:      3.8.0
Vte Version:        0.64.2
Vte Runtime Version:    0.64.2
--------------------------------------------------
GTK+ Version:       3.24.29
GDK Backend:        <GdkX11.X11Display
--------------------------------------------------
Desktop Session: /usr/share/xsessions/plasma
--------------------------------------------------
Display: :0
RGBA visual: True
Composited: True
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `ls` renders directories as bold font with the expectation that the text will appear in bright color. As explained by Guake developers this is non-standard behavior used with old terminals that did not supported fonts. Guake follows the ANSI standard and renders the text correctly.

The solution is to tweak the ls colors accordingly.